# How to combine LaTeX fonts with system fonts in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math

I am using URW Palladio L for my main text font. I have no math font of URW Palladio L on my system installed, but I like the math font of [Bitstream Charter](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/charter/). Alternateively I could also use the [URW Palladio font of LaTeX](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/palatino/).

This is how I set my main font

```
\setmainfont{URW Palladio L}
```

What about the math font? Should I use `\setmathfont`, but to what value, it's 
not a system font. If I simply add the package, it looks like I get the behavior I want, except that the font for the Bibliography heading, title etc. becomes a font I have not seen yet.

```
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
```

This seems really bogus, how I solve this properly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The TeX Gyre Pagella Math font for `unicode-math` is specifically designed for combining with Palladio (the TeX Gyre Pagella text font is based on URW Palladio).

Comment: @egreg Thanks for pointing out. So I would go to http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/download/index_html#Pagella_Math, download the font, and add it through `\setmathfont{TG Pagella Math}`?

Comment: If you're running an update TeX Live distribution, you already have the font.

Comment: `Asana Math` (based on `pxfonts`) is also suitable.

Comment: @RevMoon: You sould use `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}`, not `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There're many possible solutions, for example:

- A modern solution, use `TeX Gyre Pagella` (a Palatino clone) together with `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` or `Asana Math`.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % or URW Palladio L

  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}


  \begin{document}

  Let $f$ be holomorphic on a closed disc $\overline{D}(z_0, R)$, $R>0$. Let $C_R$ be the circle bounding the disc. Then $f$ has a power series expansion
  \[
    f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z-z_0)^n}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}
      \int_{C_R} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z_0)^{n+1}} \mathrm{d}\zeta.
  \]

  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]

  ```
  ......
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % or URW Palladio L
  \setmathfont{Asana Math}
  ......
  ```

  [image]
- A traditional solution, use `pxfonts` or `newpxtext`/`newpxmath` package. Why not? We don't always need `fontspec` to select the main font. Note that you may need to change the font encoding between `T1`/`OT1` and `EU1` manually sometimes.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \newfontfamily\inconsolata{Inconsolatazi4}

  \usepackage{pxfonts}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  \begin{document}

  Let $f$ be holomorphic on a closed disc $\overline{D}(z_0, R)$, $R>0$. Let $C_R$ be the circle bounding the disc. Then $f$ has a power series expansion
  \[
    f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z-z_0)^n}{2\piup\mathrm{i}}
      \int_{C_R} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z_0)^{n+1}} \mathrm{d}\zeta.
  \]

  {\inconsolata Something special. 01234}

  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]
- What exactly you want — Palatino together with `mathdesign`. There is nothing magic:

  ```
  ......
  \usepackage[charter]{mathdesign} % Use it before fontspec
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % or URW Palladio L
  ......
  ```

  [image]